# Avoid showing back dropdown on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation with dropdown menus. The dropdown div appears when I hover the corresponding link, only with CSS code.

```
 my-link:hover {
      .dropdown {
        visibility: visible;
      }
 }
```

The problem is that when I move the mouse and very quickly put it back on the dropdown before it completely disappear, it shows the dropdown back, even though the hover effect is on the link, not the actual dropdown.

I'm not sure if there is anyway to avoid this, because it creates a super bad UX

Thanks a lot

Comment: maybe add also `hover` to `.dropdown`

Comment: If I do this it will even more show the dropdown on hover no?
What I want is to avoid the dropdown showing back when I hover it